# close votes not displaying

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I tried searching if anyone has reported this bug but seems like I am the first one to notice it.

Till few minutes ago, [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794748/count-semi-matching-columns-using-excel-vba) question showed two close votes. And now suddenly that is no longer visible. So I tried to re-vote it but it says that I have already voted (But Of Course). Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

I am using FireFox but the same can be seen in IE as well. I closed and restarted the browser but still can't see the number of votes.

Is anyone else also facing this issue or is it just me?

Comment: Well, the question proposed as a duplicate was deleted.  That may have been the cause here.

Comment: @ServyL: Ah! That may be the reason. In such a case shouldn't the votes be negated? What I mean is when I click on Close button again, it should have reset my vote?

Comment: @SiddharthRout When a close vote is retracted (either by you, or by the system), it can't be cast again.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks :). I was aware about votes retracted by me but not by the system. Learned a new thing today! However now if the question is say `Broad`, I will not be able to vote it. Isn't that a problem. I understand that someone else might notice that and close appropriately but then my vote is simply wasted in such a scenario? I understand if I retract it but why by the system?